# Java - Problemas com geração de mapa normal

Tags: java, imagem

Olá, estou com um problema na geração de um mapa de textura normal, gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de "suavizar" as transições de tons.

Imagem original (esquerda) e mapa gerado (direita)
[image: Imagem original (esquerda) e mapa gerado (direita)]
Como podem ver, o mapa gerado possui "degraus" em quase todas as transições de tom de cor.

O código referente à geração do mapa:

```java
public static BufferedImage[] getNormal(BufferedImage source, int contrast, int brightness, float smoothness, float power) {
        BufferedImageOp op = new RescaleOp(contrast / 100f, brightness, null);
        BufferedImage input = op.filter(toGrayscale(source), null);
        BufferedImage output = new BufferedImage(input.getWidth(), input.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        WritableRaster outRaster = output.getRaster();

        for (int y = 1; y < output.getHeight() - 1; y++) {
            for (int x = 1; x < output.getWidth() - 1; x++) {
                Vec3d xNormal = new Vec3d(1, 0, power * Math.sin(Math.atan((input.getRGB(x - 1, y) - input.getRGB(x + 1, y)))));
                Vec3d yNormal = new Vec3d(0, 1, power * Math.sin(Math.atan((input.getRGB(x, y - 1) - input.getRGB(x, y + 1)))));

                Vec3d normal = new Vec3d();
                normal.cross(xNormal, yNormal);
                normal.normalize();

                int[] rgb = {
                        (int) (((normal.x + 1f) / 2) * 255),
                        (int) (((normal.y + 1f) / 2) * 255),
                        (int) (((normal.z + 1f) / 2) * 255)
                };

                outRaster.setPixel(x, y, rgb);
            }
        }

        output.setData(outRaster);
        return new BufferedImage[]{input, output};
    }
```

Esta é minha dúvida, desde já sou grato.

Comment: O que vc quer fazer especificamente? Deixar a diferença mais nítida, um degrade entre cores?

Comment: Eu gostaria de remover, ou ao menos suavizar os "degrais" que podem ser observados no mapa, eu tentei vários métodos mas eles sempre estão presentes nos eixos X e Y do mapa normal.

Comment: Tem o projeto no git?

Comment: Tenho, mas já consegui fazer de outra forma, obrigado pela ajuda mesmo assim!
Ainda assim, estou curioso do porque ficou desse jeito nesse exemplo.